# How to display image whose src are imported from json file, and is required to display json list in reactjs through mapping function?

Tags: reactjs, json

i am trying to import list from json file the file contains image url which is local directory. now my problem is when i used in reactjs by using mapping function it is not display on the screen. i am try below method to display in img tag
`<img src={require('../images/mern.png')} alt="img"/>`} this work fine by it not fulfill my needs because i our scenario we want to use map function and through map item i.e. item.image image url are imported. but when we pass item.image in `<img src={item.image}/>` the image is not displayed on the screen. i try both below method but failed.

```html
<img src={`${item.image}`} alt="img"/>
<img src={item.image} alt="img"/>
```

and here is json file

```json
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "image": "../images/mern.png",
    "title": "React Context",
    "content": "react context is used in reactjs for holding data.",
    "author": "johns smith",
    "date": "April 17, 2023"
  },
]
```

suggest me way to solve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `{data.map(item => (
        <img key={item.id} src={require(`\`../images/${item.image}`\`)} alt="img" />
      ))}`